# How to make announcement banner cookie expire after specific time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jekyll, expired-cookies

I want to make my announcement banner expire after 14 days. How would I have to change the following code to make that work?

```js
//  Announcement Banner
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var element = document.querySelector("div");
var body = document.querySelector("body");

document
.getElementById("top-site-message-hide")
.addEventListener("click", function() {
    element.classList.toggle("yay");
    button.classList.toggle("yay");
    body.classList.toggle("yay");
    document.cookie =
    "cookie2=cocoMessageHide; expires=Fri, 3 Aug 2050 20:47:11 UTC; path=/";
});

if (document.cookie.indexOf("cookie2=") >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("top-site-message-wrapper").style.display = "none";
    body.style.paddingTop = "0px";
}
```

I tried a lot of different solutions. I think there would have to be a line that replaces the following line:

```js
document.cookie =
"cookie2=cocoMessageHide; expires=Fri, 3 Aug 2050 20:47:11 UTC; path=/";
```

But I am not yet really experienced in JavaScript and JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Date()` combined with `setDate()` and `getDate()` to calcutate the currentDate + 14 days and then insert it into the `expires`  part of your cookie.

```
//  Announcement Banner
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var element = document.querySelector("div");
var body = document.querySelector("body");

document.getElementById("top-site-message-hide").addEventListener("click", function() {
  element.classList.toggle("yay");
  button.classList.toggle("yay");
  body.classList.toggle("yay");

  // Calculate date 14 days from now
  var expiryDate = new Date();
  expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() + 14);

  // Set the cookie with the new expiry date
  document.cookie =
    "cookie2=cocoMessageHide; expires=" + expiryDate.toUTCString() + "; path=/";
});

if (document.cookie.indexOf("cookie2=") >= 0) {
  document.getElementById("top-site-message-wrapper").style.display = "none";
  body.style.paddingTop = "0px";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I added this and I think that works. The only thing that is not really good it that even though when it gets closed for the first time and that is actually stored. It opens for about 1 second every time I click on another link in the menu and than closes again which is really annoying. Is there a way to not make it load after the user has closed it?